# I'm studying analytical mechanics and it states that it always true that generalized coordinates times generalized forces have the dimension of energy

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, dimensional-analysis

Since the terms $q$ "generalized coordinates" are not necessarily ‘lengths’, the quantities $Q$ "generalized forces" also do not necessarily have the dimension of a ‘force’. However, it is always true that: $[Q]\cdot [q] =$ energy.
Why the units of energy do not change?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it follows directly from the definition of [generalized forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_forces)
$$ Q_j~:=~\sum_{i=1}^N {\bf F}_i \cdot \frac{\partial {\bf r}_i}{\partial q^j}$$
that the the [virtual work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work) is
$$ \delta W~=~\sum_{i=1}^N {\bf F}_i \cdot \delta {\bf r}_i~=~\sum_{j=1}^n Q_j\delta q^j, $$
and hence that the product
$$[Q_j][q^j]~=~\text{dim. of work}~=~\text{dim. of energy}.$$

Comment: does it have a physical meaning?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: still not clear why the dim. of work does not change either?